# How can I create a view in DbA that references a table in DbB?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to setup a view in Database A that references a table in Database B?

I'm getting the following error:

> Cannot schema bind view 'dbo.AGView' because name 'dbB..AG2Table' is
>   invalid for schema binding. Names must be in two-part format and an
>   object cannot reference itself.

```
USE [dbA]
GO
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.views WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[AGView]'))
DROP VIEW [dbo].[AGView]
GO
USE [dbA]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[AGView] WITH SCHEMABINDING AS

   SELECT ag.Id AS [AGId], ag.Name AS [AGName]
   FROM dbB..AG2Table agcag
   JOIN dbB..AGTable ag on ag.Id = agcag.Id
GO
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143199/tsql-create-a-view-that-accesses-multiple-databases

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a view that uses a linked server to another database using 3-part naming `[databaseName].[schemaName].[tableName]`

You **cannot** have the `WITH SCHEMABINDING` clause.  Using `WITH SCHEMABINDING` prevents schema modifications on the tables used in the view.  The view `AGView` within `dbA` has no way to ensure the schema of the table form `dbB` has not been modified.