# Can a Sql Server View reference a table in a different database?

Tags: sql-server

I have a third party Sql Server data, which I need to use as a data source for my custom database, without duplicating data.
One thing, which comes to mind is to create a View in my custom database, which would reference one or more tables from this third party database.
Is this possible with Sql Server 2014?

Comment: Try it and find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as long as they're on the same server, [TSQL: Create a view that accesses multiple databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143199/tsql-create-a-view-that-accesses-multiple-databases) . If they're on different servers, then you'd have to create a linked server, which I wouldn't suggest unless you're aware of the pitfalls.

Answer (score 1):

Yes very much it is possible but you need to fully qualify the table name like

```
create view testview
as
select * from db_name.schema_name.table_name
```