# Get Records Matched on Multiple Fields From Tables in Separate Databases

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm doing this with LINQ, but could possibly entertain creating a stored procedure for this. I have a working solution that retrieves both record lists and then filters with `.Join()` in memory. I am looking for an improvement to this or a correction to my failed use of `.Any()` so I don't need to load the full list of records for both first.

Situation:

I have two tables that are in different DBs (so no key/navigation prop relationships and I can't change this :/).

Table 1 is a list of Foos.

```
Foo Entity Properties: ID, ..., prop1, prop2, prop3, ...
```

Table 2 is a collection of Bars that match a unique combination of three properties found in a Foo. There is a unique key for (prop1, prop2, prop3). I didn't use a composite primary key since this is part of a web app and that would complicate navigation.

```
Bar Entity Properties: ID, prop1, prop2, prop3, ...
```

I need to retrieve all Bars that match a combo from the active Foos.

I've looked into potential solutions that use .Any() / .Exists(), but they have not worked.

```
//This doesn't work
var foos = db1.Foos.Where(d => d.IsActive)
                   .Select(c => new 
                   {
                       c.prop1,
                       c.prop2,
                       c.prop3,
                   })
                   .ToList();

var fooBars = db2.Bars.Where(b => foos.Any(f => f == new { b.prop1,
                                                           b.prop2,
                                                           b.prop3 }))
                      .ToList();
```

My working solution: (see below as Answer)

I don't think that there is a way to combine this into one query since the entities are in different DbContexts, but is there a better way to retrieve filtered results without getting the entire list of bars first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you only need to load entities. You can create a view in db2 that links to tables in db1. The view will be available in your db2 context.

[TSQL: Create a view that accesses multiple databases](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2143199/532498)

Comment: I ended up implementing a view for the join. I can give the view a self-describing name, but this method doesn't have the benefit of explicitly self-documented logic that a LINQ query in the code has.

Answer (score 0):

My current working solution:

```
var foos = db1.Foos.Where(d => d.IsActive)
                   .Select(c => new 
                   {
                       c.prop1,
                       c.prop2,
                       c.prop3,
                   })
                   .ToList();

var bars = db2.Bars.ToList();

var fooBars = bars.Join(foos,
                        x => new { x.prop1, x.prop2, x.prop3 },
                        y => y,
                        (x, y) => x)
                  .ToList();
```

This is not ideal as it loads every Bar (3k+ records) when I only will be looking for the ~200 Bars that match the prop combos of my active Foos.

If anyone has a better solution, I'll accept that, but this works for now.