# What is the canonical way to select same query over multiple db's and union them?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have 9 databases in my SQL Server setup. Let's call them ONE_DB, TWO_DB etc. A quite common task I find myself doing is extracting some data from all nine instances (usually quite small tables like config etc) with the same query for the same table but over all databases. I would love a `union all select interesting_col from *.dbo.tableX`

I have come up with one way to do this, based on other questions here on SO, but I am not quite content with this solution. Lets say I only want one column from one table, I first run the SQL query below...

```
declare @db varchar(30)
declare @db_list varchar(200)
set @db = ''
set @db_list = 'ONE_DB,TWO_DB,THREE_DB,FOUR_DB,FIVE_DB,SIX_DB,SEVEN_DB,EIGHT_DB,NINE_DB'

while len(@db_list) > 0
begin
  set @db = left(@db_list, charindex(',', @db_list+',')-1);
  set @db_list = stuff(@db_list, 1, charindex(',', @db_list+','), '');
  exec ( 'use '+@db+'; select tx.interesting_columns from dbo.TableX as tx;')
end
```

... and then i copy-paste the 9 result sets to Excel manually. Of course I normally do some more processing in the select statement such as different joins, aggregations, case-clauses etc. but I guess you get the point.

This process is quite okay, but the code is not very easy to read when there are more complex select statements. It is also quite difficult for a new person to read this code as the syntax highlighter interprets all the interesting stuff (the select statement) as a string.

What is the "good" way to deal with this?

Comment: Could you [create a multi-database view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143199/tsql-create-a-view-that-accesses-multiple-databases) for each table you want to perform these operations on?

Comment: If you have an identical table with different data across multiple databases you might have a design issue. Is this the case?

Comment: are the on same server ? if yes use for eachdb and filter db names.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid i wouldnt call it a design issue. there are multiple instances of the "same" database for different customers, you could say...

Comment: @sandeeprawat yes it is on the same server. would i get the resultes joined together using eachdb?

Comment: You could dynamically build (and execute) a single `UNION ALL` query that would spit the results out for you in one grid in SSMS. As in `select column from DB1.dbo.Table1 UNION ALL  select column from DB2.dbo.Table1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using the Server Group feature of SQL Server Management Studio to execute an ad-hoc query against multiple servers (or multiple databases on the same server in your case) and automatically union the results. This can be done as follows.

1) Right-click on the Local Server Groups node in SSMS Object Explorer, select New Server Group, and give it a mnemonic name (e.g. DevServerDatabases).

2) Right-click on the new group name, select New Server Registration, specify:

- server name = name of server
- registered server name = name of database
- database name (connection properties tab) = name of database
- repeat step 2 for each database

Once all databases are added to the group, right-click on the group name and select New query. Enter the ad-hoc query in the window and execute. The result set will contain the union of all the query results plus the database name (`Server Name` column), which can be turned on or off ((Tools-->Options-->Query Results-->SQL Server-->Multiserver Results).

Comment: This is close to ideal for my use case! Simple to add/change/share ad hoc queries and really easy to update and change the setup. No new magic in the SQL either - which is good considering the level of SQL competence amongst my collegues!

Answer (score 2):

With the help of a Parse/Spit function and using a "**token**" for the DB Name

```
Declare @db_list varchar(max) = 'ONE_DB,TWO_DB,THREE_DB,FOUR_DB,FIVE_DB,SIX_DB,SEVEN_DB,EIGHT_DB,NINE_DB'
Declare @cmd     varchar(max) = ';Use <<dbname>>; select interesting_col from dbo.tableX'
Declare @SQL     varchar(max) = '>>>'

Select @SQL = Replace(Replace(@SQL+replace(@cmd,'<<dbname>>',QuoteName(RetVal))+char(13),'>>>Union All',''),'>>>','')
 From [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](@db_list,',')

Exec(@SQL)
```

> **Example 1**

```
Declare @cmd     varchar(max) = ';Use <<dbname>>; select interesting_col
```

The SQL Generated is

```
;Use [ONE_DB];select interesting_col from *.dbo.tableX
;Use [TWO_DB];select interesting_col from *.dbo.tableX
;Use [THREE_DB];select interesting_col from *.dbo.tableX
;Use [FOUR_DB];select interesting_col from *.dbo.tableX
;Use [FIVE_DB];select interesting_col from *.dbo.tableX
;Use [SIX_DB];select interesting_col from *.dbo.tableX
;Use [SEVEN_DB];select interesting_col from *.dbo.tableX
;Use [EIGHT_DB];select interesting_col from *.dbo.tableX
;Use [NINE_DB];select interesting_col from *.dbo.tableX
```

> **Example 2 - Combine Results**

```
Declare @cmd     varchar(max) = 'Union All select DBName=''<<dbname>>'',interesting_col from <<dbname>>.dbo.tableX'
```

The SQL Generated

```
 select DBName='[ONE_DB]',interesting_col from [ONE_DB].dbo.tableX
Union All select DBName='[TWO_DB]',interesting_col from [TWO_DB].dbo.tableX
Union All select DBName='[THREE_DB]',interesting_col from [THREE_DB].dbo.tableX
Union All select DBName='[FOUR_DB]',interesting_col from [FOUR_DB].dbo.tableX
Union All select DBName='[FIVE_DB]',interesting_col from [FIVE_DB].dbo.tableX
Union All select DBName='[SIX_DB]',interesting_col from [SIX_DB].dbo.tableX
Union All select DBName='[SEVEN_DB]',interesting_col from [SEVEN_DB].dbo.tableX
Union All select DBName='[EIGHT_DB]',interesting_col from [EIGHT_DB].dbo.tableX
Union All select DBName='[NINE_DB]',interesting_col from [NINE_DB].dbo.tableX
```

> **Example 3 - Execute Stored Procedure**

```
Declare @cmd     varchar(max) = ';Use <<dbname>>; exec SomeStoredProcedure'
```

The SQL Generated

```
;Use [ONE_DB]; exec SomeStoredProcedure
;Use [TWO_DB]; exec SomeStoredProcedure
;Use [THREE_DB]; exec SomeStoredProcedure
;Use [FOUR_DB]; exec SomeStoredProcedure
;Use [FIVE_DB]; exec SomeStoredProcedure
;Use [SIX_DB]; exec SomeStoredProcedure
;Use [SEVEN_DB]; exec SomeStoredProcedure
;Use [EIGHT_DB]; exec SomeStoredProcedure
;Use [NINE_DB]; exec SomeStoredProcedure
```

> **The UDF if needed**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
    From (Select x = Cast('<x>'+ Replace(@String,@Delimiter,'</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
);
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('John Cappelletti was here',' ')
```

Comment: This solution is nice since it is more genearalizable in terms of the number of databases and so on. It needs some more SQL knowledge than the solution of @Dan though. If i could set two different answers as solutions i would mark this one too! :)

Comment: @LudvigH Sure you will realize value from both.  That's why I love SO so much.  Personally, I learn something everyday... that's the fun part.  cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Use SSIS to extract data from multiple databases. In SSIS you can merge and otherwise transform the data and output it to excel. You can also schedule SSIS to run automatically.