# Is there any way in MS SQL Server to map one column of a table to another database using some sort of link?

Tags: sql-server, database

For example if I have **DB_1** and `table` in it `Table_1` and several columns in that table including `Column_5`.
Then there is a second `database` locally **DB_2** with `Table_6` and in it `Column_6`.

Is there a way to create some sort of link between `DB_1.Table_1.Column_5` and `DB_2.Table_6.Column_6` so when selects or inserts are done in `DB_1.Table_1.Column_5` it knows to get or set that data in `DB_2.Table_6.Column_6`?

I know I can sync the two together and/or use triggers but

1. We don't want to take the space in **DB_1** (to store same data at two places) and
2. Don't want to modify the higher level application that sits on top of **DB_1** to change the queries to use a column from a linked server.

At this point there is no application that sits on top of **DB_2**.

Answer (score 0):

When you do selects, you can do cross-database joins:

```
select ...
from [db1].[dbo].[table1]
join [db2].[dbo].[table2]
on ...
```

Read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/cross-database-queries?view=sql-server-ver15

As about entangling the values, you could create a trigger on `[db1].[table1]` which will `update` `[db2][table2]`.

Comment: Thanks. As I mentioned we don't want to store a copy on db1.table1 but only a link. The idea would be that you would just do a select * from [db1].[dbo].[table1] and it will know to get the column5 field from db2 by only storing some sort of link there. I guess that isn't possible?

Comment: @JohnWatt It's possible, see my answer. It does not involve copying the table from one database to the other.

Comment: @JohnWatt this approach leaves all tables where they are and does cross-database queries and triggers.

Comment: You can also create a view that accesses multiple databases: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143199/tsql-create-a-view-that-accesses-multiple-databases

Comment: How would the system know what row matches?  If all of the values are the same in all rows in both databases - but you no longer want to use the table in DB1 you can rename that table and create a synonym that points to DB2.

Comment: @Jeff It depends. There might be some pattern which can be used for the matching. For example, invoices can be identified by (year,month,day,invoice_number). If there are invoices in both databases, then you can join them by matching these fields.